# C++ setting cursor at the exact line in the file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I want to read a single line ( but not the first) from the file in C++.
Is there a smart way to accomplish this? Now I am considering using getline() and continue in the loop, but it doesnt seem to be the most optimal way? Any ideas?
Greetings

Comment: you can use fseek(), you can get help from here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Comment: If the lines are of variable length, then there is no other way then to read lines until you get to the line you want. If they are of fixed length then you can seek to `linenumber * linelength`, taking into accout `linelength` has to include the newline.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to getline as you go. There's no system-level way to scan a line at a time. If necessary and feasible, you could write an index for your file, with positions of known newlines recorded as byte positions. We can't give a proper answer without knowing what you're really trying to do, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text lines are known as *variable length records* and because of their variable length, you can't easily position to a given line in a file.

One method is to maintain a `std::vector` of file positions.  Go through the file, reading each line and recording it's position:

```
std::vector<std::streampos> text_line_positions;
// The first line starts at position 0:
text_line_positions.push_back(0);

std::string text;
while (std::getline(my_text_file, text))
{
  const std::streampos position = my_text_file.tellg();
  text_line_positions.push_back(position);
}
```

You can retrieve the file position from the vector:

```
const std::streampos line_start = text_line_positions[line_number];
```

**Edit 1:  Vector of Text**
A more optimal method could be to read each text line into a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> file_text;
std::string text;
while (std::getline(my_file, text))
{
  file_text.push_back(text);
}
```

One of the drawbacks to the above method is that you need enough memory to contain the file.
However, the access time is fast since you don't need to read the file again.

As with all optimizations, there are compromises involved.